# MFC/CLI mixed mode 'System.AccessViolationException'

Tags: multithreading, mfc, dialog, command-line-interface

I am running an MFC Dialog based application. I have a serial-comms thread running in a reference class (outside the code snippet) which sends a String^ to the dialog (so I can put the comms in a window). The problem is (as you see from commented code) that every time I try to do anything with that string (except assign it to a local variable) I get "An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in DLP_Printer_Control.exe

Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt."

In this snippet, it is the atoi that crashes. I am using atoi because I had the idea of trying to copy each string element to ASCII and then copying by value to a member CString. That didn't work. Every commented line produces an exception. I am sue its to do with trying to access something that originated in managed memory. Any workarounds suggested?

```
bool CDLP_Printer_ControlDlg::UpdateCommsWindow_right(String^ strCommsLine)
{
    CString strTemp = strCommsLine;
    LPWSTR charTemp;
    int i = 0;
    int i_len = strTemp.GetLength();

    if (i_len == 0)
        return false;

    charTemp= strTemp.GetBuffer(i_len);

    i =atoi((const char*)charTemp[0]);

    strTemp.ReleaseBuffer();


    //if (m_strCommsLeft.IsEmpty())
    //  return false;

    //LPCTSTR szTemp = (LPCTSTR)strTemp;

    //m_rightCommsLabel.SetWindowTextW((LPCTSTR)strTemp);
    //m_rightCommsLabel.SetWindowTextW(szTemp);
    //m_rightCommsLabel.SetWindowTextW(L"SUCCESS");
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> In this snippet, it is the atoi that crashes.
>
> `i =atoi((const char*)charTemp[0]);`

Short answer is that `charTemp[0]` is a `TCHAR` and ***not*** a pointer, so while the `const char *` cast allows it compile, the value that gets passed to `atoi` is ***not*** a pointer to valid memory, which causes the `System.AccessViolationException` exception. The quick fix would be to replace that line with `i = _wtoi(charTemp);`, or even `i = _ttoi(strTemp);` as discussed below.

> `LPWSTR charTemp; /*...*/ charTemp= strTemp.GetBuffer(i_len);`

This will only compile if the project is built for *Unicode*. That's the common case in Windows nowadays, but it's worth noting since you are mixing-in non-Unicode functions like `atoi` later on. For a variation that would compile correctly for both wide and narrow charsets, you could replace the declaration with the charset-neutral `LPTSTR charTemp;`.

> `i =atoi((const char*)charTemp[0]);`

This will only compile if the project is *not* built for *Unicode* since `atoi` expects a plain old `const char *` as an argument. The charset-neutral MS mapping is [_ttoi](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd5xkb5c.aspx), so after dropping the wrong `[0]` and the `const char *` cast, the code would become simply `i = _ttoi(charTemp);`.

Finally, `CString` has a built-in `LPCTSTR` operator, so there is no need to `GetBuffer/ReleaseBuffer` and use an intermediate `LPTSTR charTemp;`. The following will do the same job in one step.

```
i = _ttoi(strTemp);
```

Comment: Many thanks. The _ttoi() stopped that error, but this turned out to be a red herring. Actually, if I have a member int, then set I to this member int, the I get "Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException'" the moment I do it ;(

Comment: `if I have a member int [...]` That would happen if you called the member function via a NULL object pointer. But it's impossible to guess without an MCVE.